# Missing psych (for YAML output), while merging db to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Im uploading a ruby app to heroku, and when I use heroku run rake db:migrate, an error pops up.

warning: It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
rake aborted!

Im working on Mac and the ruby version is 2.6.0, I've tried reinstalling psych and ruby

```sh
Caused by:
LoadError: cannot load such file -- 2.5/psych.so
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/psych-3.1.0/lib/psych.rb:14:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/psych-3.1.0/lib/psych.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: Do you declare the dependency in your `Gemfile`?

Comment: @tadman yes, I uploaded an older version of the app, but I didn't modify any of the gem and its giving me that error